# Is 'window' really global in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, theory

Take this piece of JavaScript code in a browser:

```html
<script>
    console.log(window.someThing);
    var x = 12;

    function foo() {
       window.otherThing = x;
    }
</script>
```

Inside `foo` we can access `window`. We all know that, but why exactly?

- Is it some kind of special global variable?
- Or does the "root scope" (inside the `script` tag) have it as an implicit local variable and is it simply "closure-inherited" as any other local variable (like `x` above) can be?

And how does that concur with variables declared directly inside the `script` tag being set as properties of `window`? (Or is that not so?)

```html
<script>
    var x = 12;
    function() {
       console.log(window.x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No-one mentioned window is _the global object_ all global variables are properties of _window_. It is the container of global objects. (Including itself `window.window`)

Comment: @Raynos [`window.window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason why you can access *"out of scope"* or *"free"* variables in ECMAScript is the so-called *scope chain*. The scope chain is a special property from each *execution context*. As mentioned several times before, a context object looks at least like:

- [[scope]]
- Variable / Activation Object
- "this" context value

Each time you access a variable(-name) within a context (a function for instance), the lookup process always starts in its own *Activation Object*. All formal parameters, function declarations and locally defined variables (var) are stored in that special object. If the variablename was not found in that object, the search goes into the *[[Scope]]*-chain.

Each time a function(-context) is initialized, it'll copy all **parent context variable/activation objects** into its internal *[[Scope]]* property. That is what we call, a *lexical scope*. That is the reason why *[closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))* work in ECMAScript. Since the *Global context* also has an *Variable Object* (more precisely, **the variable object for the global object is the global object itself) it also gets copied into the functions *[[Scope]]* property.

That is the reason why you can access *window* from within any function :-)

The above explanation has one important conceptional conclusion: Any function in ECMAScript is a *closure*, which is true. Since every function will at least copy the *global context VO* in its *[[Scope]]* property.

Comment: Is there a way to alter the scope chain? E.g. to prevent a function from having access to the global scope?

Comment: How to access `[[Scope]]` property syntactically?

Comment: What is "VO"? (near *"global context VO"*)

Answer (score 18):

> Is window really global in JavaScript?

Yes. Unless you create a new variable called window in a narrower scope

```
function foo() {
    var window;
}
```

> Inside foo we can access window, we all know that, but why exactly?

Any function can access variables declared in a wider scope. There is nothing special about window there.

Comment: But is the scope in which window lives simply the widest scope in the scope chain, or is it a *special* global scope? How is it resolved internally at runtime by the Javascript engine?

Comment: As I said "nothing special" (well, that isn't quite true, since it is the default variable, but nothing special with regards to scope anyway).

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: It will check if there is a variable with the same name on the local scope, if none found, it will go upwards until `Object`.

Comment: @Shef Until Object? Surely window is not a static property of Object...or is it?

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: Sorry, meant to write `Window` object.

Answer (score 9):

It's all defined in ECMAScript.

The global is a *lexical* environment that doesn't have an outer lexical environment. All other environments are nested within it, and is bound to a global object with properties specified by the specification.

This places the properties of the global object at the start of the scope chain, from which all other environments inherit.

[ES 10.2.3 The Global Environment](http://es5.github.com/#x10.2.3):

> The global environment is a unique Lexical Environment which is created before any ECMAScript code is executed. The global environment’s Environment Record is an object environment record whose binding object is the global object (15.1). The global environment’s outer environment reference is null.
>
> As ECMAScript code is executed, additional properties may be added to the global object and the initial properties may be modified.

[ES 15.1 The Global Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1)

> The unique global object is created before control enters any execution context.
>
> Unless otherwise specified, the standard built-in properties of the global object have attributes {[[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}.
>
> The global object does not have a [[Construct]] internal property; it is not possible to use the global object as a constructor with the new operator.
>
> The global object does not have a [[Call]] internal property; it is not possible to invoke the global object as a function.
>
> The values of the [[Prototype]] and [[Class]] internal properties of the global object are implementation-dependent.
>
> In addition to the properties defined in this specification the global object may have additional host defined properties. This may include a property whose value is the global object itself; for example, in the HTML document object model the window property of the global object is the global object itself.

Comment: Come to think of it, `window.window.window.window.window === window.window.window.window`.

Comment: When does the compiler know when to stop so that we don't have infinite `window.window.window` etc...?

Comment: @Shaz: It is a circular reference, so it doesn't end. The compiler only creates one reference. It just happens to be a reference back to the original object on which the reference was created. That's why you can do `window.window.window...` Like this: `var obj = {}; obj.obj = obj;`. There's only one reference created but it's a reference back to the original, so you can do `obj.obj.obj.obj.obj.obj.obj === obj`.

Answer (score 6):

It has to do with the *scope chain*.

Have a look at [the presentation of Nicholas C. Zakas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU#t=5m) (starting around 5 minutes).

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the global scope is indeed just a regular one, just at the highest level.

Comment: Can you [summarise](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6679851/edit) in your answer (include the gist of it)? This resource may not stay up for ever.

Answer (score 3):

*window* is the base scope of all JavaScript objects, and it's automatically "attached" to each variables you define, unless you use "var" before the declaration, in this case the scope of the variable it's local (that means that it's contained inside the parent function, or is otherwise global too, if you are declaring your variable outside a function block). Moreover ***window*** *is defined as a constant**, that is **you can't redefine the** ***window*** **object** (you will get an error saying "type error: redeclaration of const window").

So:

```
window.foo = 5;
```

It's the same as:

```
var foo = 5;
```

Or:

```
function() {
    foo = 5;
}
```

but:

```
function() {
    var foo = 5;
}
```

In this case, "foo" is local (window.foo === undefined),

Comment: You can redefine `window`. `(function (window) { alert(window) })(1)`.

Comment: you are not redefining window in this way, you are creating a closure with an argument with name "window"... it's a different thing! :)

Comment: `function` syntax is invalid, requires a name. variable `foo=2` in `function f(){}` is not equivalent to `window.foo`

Answer (score 1):

The `window` global scope applies only to the main thread. In web workers there is no `window` global variable. Instead you have [`WorkerGlobalScope` inside a `WebWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope) and in a [`SharedWorkerGlobalScope` inside a `SharedWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorkerGlobalScope).

This worker global scope is stored in a variable called `self` and as MDN describes it:

> this scope contains the information usually conveyed by [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) objects.

This can become a problem when 3rd party code you are using in your web worker is using the window object. This can be easily solved by declaring a `window` variable as suggested by @FelipeMicaroniLalli in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22160937/1697459) like this:

```
var window = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the book [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748), as I understand, Douglas Crockford explains that `window` is the global object of the web browser that contains all the global variables. It is like the One Ring...

Comment: What is "the One Ring"? Is it a [Tolkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien) reference? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is a reference to The Lord Of The Rings