# Why top level functions are created as methods of window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

When we define a top level named function in Javascript, it becomes a method of the *window* object. What is the reason for this design decision?

Comment: You could ask Brendan Eich? https://brendaneich.com/tag/javascript/. He started the whole thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript always run in a particular global context.
In a browser environment that is the window object, so when you define a global, you're actually adding it to window...

Here is another excellent stackoverflow answer explaining why this is so:
[Is window really global in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript)

Comment: This is true, but does not explain why `window` was chosen instead of a dedicated global object. To be fair though, I don't know if this answer is easy to find if you haven't been in involved in browser / JS engine development

Comment: @FelixKling what would you suggest be the topmost context then? :)

Comment: As I said, you could simply have another *dedicated* global object, accessible as `global`, like in Node.js. That a global has to exist is clear, but why is it `window`?

Comment: @FelixKling: The concept is the same in NodeJS. The global is just exposed under a different name, which is expected since the name `window` wouldn't make much sense on a server. In other words, `window` in a browser, and `global` in NodeJS *is* the dedicated global object.

Comment: @squint: I know. But `window` contains other properties as well, which are not part of the ES specification. I know that the spec explicitly allows this, but since `window` already contains many DOM related properties, using a dedicated global object for global variables only, instead of such a mix up, doesn't seem to be a bad solution. That is what I meant.

Comment: @FelixKling: I guess I see what you're saying. In a sense, the browsers do this, but it's via the object prototype chain. Node doesn't really though AFAIK, unless you're talking about their local `exports` objects?

Comment: @squint: You are right, in Node it's different again because of the module system (I remember having a hard time wrapping some generic JS code to make it work in Node due to how globals work there). I didn't mean `exports` though. Anyway, I think you got my point :)

Comment: Basically because we're talking about browsers, and pretty much a "window" of the browser is an instance of the browser itself. Can't get more "global" than that. :)
Node doesn't run in a browser window, hence it would have been semantically incorrect to have the same "window" object as the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the reason for this design decision?

I can't answer that, we'd have to ask the guy who designed the language, and the committee that maintains its specification. But maybe this will give you some insights: internally, variables (local or global) are always stored in "Lexical Environment" objects. So, they are always properties, and they even have their own properties (to mark them as read-only, non-deletable, etc.).

The environment objects are not exposed in browser JavaScript, except for the global object (as pointed out by squint in the comments, ECMAScript doesn't actually require that the global variable object be exposed, that's up to the implementation.)

It happens that it was decided that the global object is the same as the window object in browsers. Why? Again, I can't answer that. They just decided not to use a dedicated `global` (or whatever) identifier.

Comment: +1 I'd only add the small point that ECMAScript doesn't actually require that the global variable object be exposed. An implementation could decide to not expose it, and it would be compliant.

Comment: Thanks, added a note about that. But let me ask: in implementations where it's not exposed (if you know any), is it still be possible to access stuff like `parseInt` and the `Object` constructor?

Comment: Since `parseInt` and `Object` are properties of the global object and therefore global variables, they can still be accessed. Even if the object itself is not exposed, those properties/variables will be looked up through the scope chain. I have to say though that I don't know such an implementation, this is my interpretation from the specification.

Comment: Yeah, what @FelixKling said. :-) If you're curious, the last paragraph of [15.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1) is where the `window` property is described as an example of a "host" property.

Comment: @squint So that's the reason for `window.window.window.window...`. Without it, `window` itself wouldn't be exposed!

Comment: Exactly. They could *(if the spec allowed it)* do the same in function scopes too. All they'd need to do would be to add a property to the local variable object that points back to that object, and that property would show up as a variable exposing that object.