# Is the window object in a browser a closure or some other construct?

Tags: javascript

I am not a full-time JS dev although I feel like I've worked with it forever. Most of the discussion of closures makes sense. I'm curious if the global `window` object is just a global closure? I have read http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/30/is-javascripts-global-scope-really-just-a-closure/ but it doesn't seem to answer the question in a yes-or-no way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an object, so it can't be a closure (closures are functions, plus a scope chain). It's also the global scope object, as all global variables are properties of `window`<sup>1</sup>.

The article you mentioned says:

> It looks like global scope is nothing more than the bi-product of the closure support that JavaScript has built into it, in combination with the outermost scope of the runtime (a DOMWindow or some other scope for CommonJS implementations).

The author is not saying that `window` is a closure, it's just saying that everything has access to the global scope for the same reason variables trapped in closures are visible in inner scopes. That is true.

---

<sup>1</sup> That includes references to the `window` object itself, as pointed out by Rocket Hazmat. And there's more than one, there's `window`, `self`, `top`... So `window.window.top.window.self === window`. In fact, the reason `window` is globally accessible is because there is a reference to it in the global object (`=== itself`). See also: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16779427/825789) to *[Why top level functions are created as methods of window in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778966/why-top-level-functions-are-created-as-methods-of-window-in-javascript)*, and the comments below it.

Comment: It is also the root object of the DOM.

Comment: "all global variables are properties of `window`", such as `window`.  So, you can access: `window.window` :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, that's funny and worth mentioning. Added a note about it.

Comment: thx, makes more sense now. appreciate the help; will spend some tiem with Chrome console trying to sort out

Answer (score 1):

It's an object.  You can add properties to it and call properties from it.  Many of the standard functions you use are actually part of the `window` object, but can be left out.  If you create a new window in a script, it will have its own `window` object that you can reference and manipulate.

Closures create an scope for variables, just as a window creates a scope.  However, a closure is a function and therefore a `window` object is not a closure.