# whatever is added to window object is global?

Tags: javascript, window-object

whatever is accessible in window object, is global? I am confused if whatever is contained in window object or whatever is accessible via window. is global?

I'm trying to type in window.something in the console , so whatever is accessible with "window." 
are they all global?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, but only those properties directly assigned to `window`. If you'd create a property to `window` as an object, like `window.obj = {prop: 'Prop'};`, `prop` in `obj` is not global.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in browsers, `window` is the global object.

Comment: and whatever is accesible under window. is global too right? So basically if I can access a variable with window.variablename then variablename is global . Is it?