# JavaScript local scope function

Tags: javascript

Is my code local scope?

To me it seems as `myScope` is local scope and that it can be accesses through `_hello` is this assumption correct?

```
var myScope = function () {

    function hiThere() {
        //...
    }

    function bye() {
        /...
    }

    return {
       hiThere:hiThere,
       bye:bye  
    };

    //... more functions

}();


if (window._hello) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _hello.length; i++) {       
        var method = _hello[i].shift();
        try {
            myScope[method].apply(myScope, _hello[i]);
        } catch (err) {
            //console.log(err);
        }
    }
};
window._hello = {
    push: function() {
        try {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
            var method = args[0].shift();
            myScope[method].apply(myScope, args);
        }
        catch(err) { 
            //console.log(err);
        }  
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but if this javascript runs in a browser (which I assume it does given the `window`), all variables declared toplevel like that are global and can be accessed as `window.varname`.

Now even if this weren't in a browser, or if it were wrapped in a function, you could still access `myScope` through `_hello`, because of [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).