# global & local var and this operator in js

Tags: javascript, scope, this, global, local

I am a little bit confused with global, local var and this operator in js.
I have to code examples and their output, if someone can explain why the output is so:

```
var x="10";
function f() {
    var x="4";
    alert(this.x);
    function g() {alert(x);}
    g();
}
f();
```

the output is: alert(10) and then alert(4), why? what is the difference with the this operator?

the secend example:

```
enter code here

 var y="5";
var x="10";
x=y;
function f()
{
    y="4";
     alert(this.y);
     function g() {alert(y);}
     g();
}
alert(y);
f();
```

the output is:alert(4) then alert(5) anf then alert(4), why again? what the hidden semantic of "this" operator that I don't see?

if someone can give a general rules for global,local,this,scope in js and their extreme cases please.

Comment: This may help you: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript

Comment: When `this` is always bound to the object a method is called on (except in arrow functions), what object could this be in your code? Do you apply `f` as a method at all (e.g. `obj.f()`)? Do you see any object? So `this` is bound implicitly to the the global object (`window` in browsers). Since `x` and `y` are in the global scope (not defined within a function), they are accessible in `window`.

Answer (score 0):

- Accessing a variable (e.g. `x`) will point to the variable `x` in the *current scope* (e.g. the variable `x` defined *inside* your function).
- The value of `this.x`, however, depends on *where* it is called. `this` is bound to an object and, in this case, points to the global `window` object which resolves to `window.x`, i.e. the *global* `x`.

You can find more information about [`this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and note that you code would behave differently in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explanation :

```
var x="10";
function f() {
    var x="4"; // This is a local variable and not a property of f
    alert(this.x); // "this" represent the global scope because you do not a new instance of f with the keyword "new" like this new f()
    function g() {alert(x);} // The x variable reference the parent scope which is f
    g();
}
f();
```