# Are names in function scope not considered properties?

Tags: javascript

For the below code,

```
function Foo(value) {
  property = value
  alert('Hello ' + value);
  this.y = value;
}

Foo.prototype.x = 10;

Foo.prototype.calculate = function (input) {
  console.log('calculated value: ' + input*2);
}

b = new Foo(20);
c = new Foo(30);
```

Below is my understanding,

### [image]

But, am expecting name `property` and name `alert` to be as properties, part of `Foo`, unlike as shown below,

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo)
Array [ "prototype", "length", "name" ]
```

Why `property` & `alert` are not considered properties of `Foo`?

Comment: Notice, that undeclared `property` in `Foo` creates an implicit global variable.

Comment: @Teemu  If `property`'s scope is global within that js file(module). What is the scope of `alert`?

Comment: `alert` in your code invokes a global function, it's a function call, it is not particulary scoped to anywhere.

Comment: @Teemu 1) Global function, you mean `window` scope, `window['alert']`? 2) When you say, implicit global variable `x`, you mean `window['x']` , as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680091/3317808)?

Comment: 1) In a way, yes, `alert` is a system defined DOM property in `window` object. 2) The linked answer describes "implicit global" quite well.

Comment: If you need more info, T. J. Crowder (a commendable user at SO) has written about the [horror of the implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search?q=horror+of+implicit) in his blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a property on an object, you have to explicitly refer to the object (as you do with `this.y = value;`) or inherit it on the prototype chain.

Since you didn't do that, they are not properties. They are variables.

Since there were not declared with `var` (or `let`, or anything else that would limit the scope), they are **global** variables. (If you were using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (always use strict mode) it would be an error instead).

Comment: @overexchange — Both. It's a variable. "Having a name" is an intrinsic part of what a variable is. The value of the variable is a reference to a [function supplied by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). All functions are objects.

Comment: In `Foo.prototype`, Would you term `x` as property or something else? Because it is common to all instances of `Foo`.

Comment: It's a property of the prototype object. It is made available (unless masked) as a property on all instances of Foo through the prototype chain.

Comment: You explicitly refer to the object with `Foo.prototype`.

Comment: So, variables are just part of execution of code(function)