# JavaScript syntax highlighting -- is status a keyword? -- what's it used for?

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax-highlighting

My vim syntax highlighting just lead me to believe that `status` is a keyword in JavaScript.

Searching around all I can find are articles about `window.status` in browser JavaScript. Is this the meaning of this 'keyword' `status` or is there something different going on?

What is the keyword `status`?

Comment: status is not a javascript keyword as far as I've been able to find - where does your information come from? the `status` in `window.status` does not make `status` a keyword ... it is a `property` of window - see [window.status "documentation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) - perhaps you are thinking of `static`?

Comment: I'm not seeing it in the specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words

Comment: "I just noticed that `status` is a keyword in JavaScript" I don't know where you got that information because it absolutely [is not](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-keywords).

Comment: Ahh I see, let me reword my question, it was foolish to assume it was a keyword just because of my syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is actually incorrect. I probably confounded `static` with `status`. The Mozilla website has a page about the [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status). It may have been done that way so you do not try to use that name as a variable. That way you would not inadvertently update the status bar of your browser. The feature doesn't work anymore, but I guess the in editors is lagging.

---

In the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) (which is easier to read than the [ECMA reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-left-hand-side-expressions),) we find the `status` keyword under the *Future reserved keywords* section.

So, it is viewed as a keyword.

However, JavaScript accepts reserved keywords in various places such as after a period as in:

```
a = {}
a.default = 123
a.status = 555
```

Here I set the `default` and `status` members of object `a` even though these two names are viewed as reserved keywords in the language.

Actually, if you have been using Promise objects, you may have noticed the `catch` keyword used as one of the possible callbacks:

```
Promise.all([a, b, c])
       .then(...)
       .catch(...)     <-- this is a reserved keyword
       .finally(...)   <-- this is a reserved keyword
```

Here are the pertinent grammar entries:

```
Identifier :
    IdentifierName but not ReservedWord

MemberExpression :
    PrimaryExpression
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    MemberExpression . IdentifierName     <-- look at this one
    MemberExpression TemplateLiteral
    SuperProperty
    MetaProperty
    new MemberExpression Arguments
```

An [`IdentifierName`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-IdentifierName) is any identifier (more or less `[A-Z_$][A-Z_0-9$]*`, plus all Unicode characters... they actually follow the Unicode definition of an identifier.) That includes reserved keywords.

As we can see, you are not supposed to start an expression with a `ReserverWord`, except for a new exception like `new` and `super` (not shown here, see `SuperProperty`.)

So in strict mode (i.e. in a node module) you should get an error if you write:

```
status = 123
```

In non-strict mode, `status` is not a reserved keyword and therefore it is allowed.

One way to make sure that it works when you access variable members is to use the array syntax. For example:

```
a['default'] = 123
a['status'] = 555
```

Also that way the names do not get highlighted as reserved keywords by your editor.

Comment: The linked Mozilla documentation doesn't contain the `status` keyword (including the version [at the time of this answer](http://web.archive.org/web/20181115173231/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)) 

Comment: @AdamMillerchip You are right. My answer is wrong. I think I was mistaken as there is a `static` reserved keyword. [`status` was _just_ a global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

Answer (score 2):

If you play around in your console. You can do the following:

```
-> status
<- ""

-> window.status
<- ""

-> status='333'
<- "333"

-> status
<- "333"

-> window.status
<- "333"
```

This to me indicates that the keyword `status` is simply an alias for the `window.status` property. What exactly `window.status` does I am not sure.

EDIT: After reading the comment below, I realized that properties of the windows object are *essentially* global. So this makes status the same as window.status and NOT an alias as I mention above.

See this Stack Overflow about the window object:
[Is window really global in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript)

Comment: it's not an alias ... `window.status === status` ... it's as much an alias as `setTimout` is for `window.setTimeout` - i.e, it's not an alias at all

Comment: window-ception :p

Comment: Appreciate the answer Jonathan, I guess my syntax highlighting is geared for browser JavaScript then?