# What is the difference between 'Window' and 'global' types of window object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's console, when I access:

```
window
```

[image: Types of window objects]

This difference arises when I try to access the `window` object from different contexts like the `top` context or an `iFrame` context etc.

Can someone please explain what these different `window` objects mean and are there other 'types' as well ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is window really global in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript)