# ReferenceError: Javascript function is not defined when main function is called from AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a function defined in the my footer that is loaded for all of the pages on my website.  It contains mostly shared scripts and functions.  The function is like:

```
function replaceOrderRow (accession) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Orders/order_row_getByAccession',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"data-accession":  accession},
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $("[data-accession=" + accession + "].worklist").replaceWith(data.markup);
            colorrows ($('#patientdiv .worklist, #orderswrapper .worklist'));
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
}
```

This works fine when called by another script/function that is also defined in the footer page.

I am then also loading some content via AJAX into a div dynamically that has mostly HTML markup, but also a number of scripts specific to that content.  Most of those scripts load and work fine, but when I try to call the replaceOrderRow function from a function defined in the content that is dynamically loaded I get the "ReferenceError: replaceOrderRow is not defined" error message in the console.  Probably not good practice to load scripts dynamically via AJAX.

The function on the page that is loaded dynamically has an AJAX call, and the problem is in the success/done (I have changed to .done/.fail/.always for most of my other calls).  This one older, but should not make a difference.  The issue is after the $('#closeorderoverlay').on('click', function(e) . . ., and I would not be surprised if the getOrderCount(patientrow) call does not work either, although the script errors out before it gets there.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ManagePatients/orderform',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: extradata,
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

            $('#modalDiv').html(data);
            $('#modalDiv').show();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");

            $('#closeorderoverlay').on('click', function(e) {

                if (accession != undefined) {

                replaceOrderRow(accession);

                }
                if($("#orderswrapper").length == 0) { // on the patients page
                patientrow = $("#patientswrapper").find("[data-mrn='" + mrn + "']");
                patientrow.find(".showorders").trigger("click");
                getOrderCount(patientrow);
                }
                $('#modalDiv').html("");
                $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
                $('#modalDiv').hide();
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);


            });
. . . . .
. . . . .
```

I did move the functions around quite a bit, and when I move the function on the AJAX loaded page to the footer in some locations it does not work, while in others it does seem to work now.  It is not in a document ready block, but just wrapped it  tags.  It does seem that the order in which it is loaded makes a difference, although I cannot quite see exactly what the issue is.  I would rather have it still in the AJAX loaded page since it is really only needed for the content that is with that page.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's worth trying to make the `replaceOrderRow ` function global by storing it in the root `window` object? `window.replaceOrderRow = function (accession) { ...` Then I don't see why it couldn't be accessed from anywhere else

Comment: I'll play around with it.  I think it is some sort of scoping problem.

Comment: That actually does seem to do the trick.  I put the function within the footer scripts and added window.replaceOrderRow = function().  What is the difference there though if I was loading it just within <script> tags, not within a document.ready or anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript